# center bottom element to parent div

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Hi I have a little problem.
I want to add to few div centered element on bottom.
I tried this:

```
position:absolute;
min-width:73px;
min-height:52px;
margin: 0 auto;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
bottom:0px;
```

but it doesn't work.
That code set each div on the same position (bottom of vh).
I'm using bootstrap, maybe that info help to solve this problem?

Full code:

```
<div class="row container-box>

    <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1" >
//some stuff
    </div>

<a href="#second"><span id="myid" class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down "></span></a>

        </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Bootstrap has a class .center-block but just add `float:none;` to that class. So on your css make sure you have:

```
.center-block{
    float:none
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

Your HTML should look like this

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-10 center-block">
     //some stuff
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: OK, I can center my div with .center-block, but can't use position:absolute to set that on bottom:0px (center doesn't work again)

Comment: Is the class container-box your own class? And what do you mean by "I want to add to few div centered element on bottom". What do yo mean by bottom??

Comment: I am sorry but there is not a class in bootstrap called container-box. For a container in bootstrap there are two classes: container and container-fluid. http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-intro

Comment: I edited my answer. I wrote how your html should look. @KarolJankiewicz